# linking an image with text

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently developing a web app where i want users to rate an image. I am using Polldaddy.com as the source of the rating widget.

```
<div id="scriptwrapper">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var slides = [{
      img : 'slidepagepic01.jpg',
      desc : 'Cotswolds, England'
    }, {
      img : 'slidepagepic02.jpg',
      desc : 'Patagonia, Chile'
    }, {
      img : 'slidepagepic03.jpg',
      desc : 'Kauai, Hawaii'
    }, {
      img : 'slidepagepic04.jpg',
      desc : 'Morzine, France'
    }, {
     img : 'slidepagepic05.jpg',
      desc : 'Fernando De Noronha, Brazil'
    }, {
      img : 'slidepagepic06.jpg',
     desc : 'Isla Vieques, Puerto Rico'
   }];
 </script>
 </div>
 <div style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;" id="wrapper"><div
  style="position:    relative; top: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%;" id="swipeview-  
slider"><div data-upcoming-page-index="5" data-page-index="5" style="position:  
absolute; top: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%; left: -100%;" id="swipeview-masterpage- 
0"><img src="slidepagepic06.jpg" class="loading" height="470" width="328"><span>Isla  
Vieques, Puerto Rico</span></div><div class="swipeview-active" data-upcoming- 
page-index="0" data-page-index="0" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; height: 100%;  
width: 100%; left: 0%;" id="swipeview-masterpage-1"><img style="left: -1px; width:  
339px; top: 0px; height: 420px;" src="slidepagepic01.jpg" class="loading">
<span>Cotswolds, England</span></div><div data-upcoming-page-index="1" data-page- 
index="1" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%; left:   
100%;"  
id="swipeview-masterpage-2"><img src="slidepagepic02.jpg" class="loading" height="470" 
width="328"><span>Patagonia, Chile</span></div></div></div>

<ul id="nav" style="padding-left: 11px; left: 158px; width: 203px; top: 8px; height:  
18px;"><li id="prev" onclick="gallery.prev()"> - </li><li class="selected" 
onclick="gallery.goToPage(0)"><br></li><li class="" onclick="gallery.goToPage(1)">
<br></li><li class="" onclick="gallery.goToPage(2)"><br></li><li class="" 
onclick="gallery.goToPage(3)"><br></li><li class="" onclick="gallery.goToPage(4)">
<br></li><li class="" onclick="gallery.goToPage(5)"><br></li><li id="next" 
onclick="gallery.next()"> + </li></ul>
```

this coding is from seattleclouds.com and thats where i am currently building the app. The code is for an image slider. I would like to link the different images in the slider to it's own unique rating widget. Problem is I'm not sure where to insert the coding for the rating widget. I've been at this for almost 2 weeks. Please assist

Comment: 'Java' is to 'JavaScript' as 'Car' is to 'Carpet'.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest wrapping each `<img>` tag in `<a>` tags so, for example:

`<img src="slidepagepic06.jpg" class="loading" height="470" width="328"><span>Isla

Vieques, Puerto Rico</span></div><div class="swipeview-active" data-upcoming- 
page-index="0" data-page-index="0" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; height: 100%;

width: 100%; left: 0%;" id="swipeview-masterpage-1">`

would become:

`<a href="www.WIDGET URL.com"><img src="slidepagepic06.jpg" class="loading" height="470" width="328"><span>Isla

Vieques, Puerto Rico</span></div><div class="swipeview-active" data-upcoming- 
page-index="0" data-page-index="0" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; height: 100%;

width: 100%; left: 0%;" id="swipeview-masterpage-1"></a>`